# Clipping a raster without pixel displacement / shifting

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm not sure I'm writing in the right place. I looked for for answer for this question and didn't find any topic related to.

PROBLEM: when I clipped a raster either by extent or mask layer it results in a raster where the first pixel starts align to the first corner I gave. As a consequence my whole raster is shifted keeping the pixel values (probably nearst neighborhood). I also tried saving as and defining map canvas extent.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that they GDAL algorithm in the toolbox worked. Although it use the same command (if you pay attention on the console call at the bottom) the arguments order results in a different output. By selecting both option:

- Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline
- Keep resolution of output raster

Answer (score 0):

The solution did not work for me. I am using Qgis 3.4. and when I selected the option "Keep resolution of output raster" I got a *shifted raster*. By selecting only the option "Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline" I got an aligned raster. I am not sure on why this happens. Hope this works for others.

Comment: Hi Camilo, try to select both option and double check that you define the resolution to the exact same value of the raster you want to align with. I recently sis this same process in 3.4 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (QGIS 3.4.5-Madeira) I receive not shifted pixels only if I set the range (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) which is multiple of pixel size. For example in case of 30m pixels of Landsat these values should be multiple of 30.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SAGA toolbox instead - Clip Raster with Polygon. No pixel shift that way.